Blazor vs FluentValidation: child component doesn't show validation message
I'm trying to create a chain from many input components. But if I use the last one, the validation message doesn't show in component, but validation summary looks good.

InputTextOnInput (https://www.meziantou.net/validating-an-input-on-keypress-instead-of-on-change-in-blazor.htm)

@inherits InputText

<input class="@CssClass"
       value="@CurrentValue"
       @oninput="EventCallback.Factory.CreateBinder<string>(this, value => CurrentValueAsString = value, CurrentValueAsString)"
    />


InputFloatingLabel

@using System.Linq.Expressions
<div class="form-floating mb-3">
    @ChildContent
    <label for="@LabelForId">@Label</label>
    <div class="invalid-feedback"><ValidationMessage For="@ValidationMessageFor"/></div>
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter] public string LabelForId { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    [Parameter] public string Label { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    [Parameter] public Expression<Func<object>>? ValidationMessageFor { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment? ChildContent { get; set; }
}


InputTextFloatingLabel

@using System.Linq.Expressions
<InputFloatingLabel LabelForId="@Id"
                    Label="Адрес сервера"
                    ValidationMessageFor="@ValidationMessageFor">
    <InputTextOnInput @bind-Value="@Value" id="@Id" class="form-control" @bind-Value:after="OnValueChanged"/>
</InputFloatingLabel>

@code {
    [Parameter] public string? Value { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public string Id { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    [Parameter] public string Label { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    [Parameter] public Expression<Func<object>>? ValidationMessageFor { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<string?> ValueChanged { get; set; }

    private async Task OnValueChanged()
    {
        await this.ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(Value);
    }

}


parent component

<InputTextFloatingLabel @bind-Value="DatabaseConnection.Host"
                        Id="input-db-host"
                        Label="Host"
                        ValidationMessageFor="() => DatabaseConnection.Host" />

If I use InputFloatingLabel in parent component - all works fine.
Could you please help me, how to show validation message when the InputTextFloatingLabel is usend in parent?
I'm tried to use CascadeParameter EditContext and NotifyFieldChanged

Your expression doesn't work, it is null or type parameter object not conform real necessary type. Have you tried to debug your second component to see it?
